# Python: How to parse all the 'for loop' outputs to mysql update query as one variable

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup, mysql-python

Hi I've been looking for a similar thread but I couldn't find one so posting a question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

【Background】

I'm using beautifulsoup to scrape some website. What I would like to achieve is to find images that has particular relative path in the html (ex./examplefolder/image/) and turn that into a definite path by adding the prefix (ex.xxx.example.com) then parse a variable which contains the result(multiple instances) of 'for loop' to mysql update query.

【Current Code】

```
import urlparse
#find relative path in html doc
for image in soup.select('img[src^="/examplefolder/image/"]'):
    #extract src value
    path = "%(src)s" % image
    #define base url
    base_url = "xxx.example.com"
    #add it together
    image = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, path)
```

【Problem】

When I execute the above script on console it returns me all the images path, so far so good, however, if I use 'image' as a variable in mysql query, it only saves the last value

example output:

> > > xxx.example.com/examplefolder/image/1.jpg
> > >
> > > xxx.example.com/examplefolder/image/2.jpg
> > >
> > > xxx.example.com/examplefolder/image/3.jpg
> > >
> > > xxx.example.com/examplefolder/image/4.jpg
> > >
> > > xxx.example.com/examplefolder/image/5.jpg <- only the last value gets stored

it is simply because 'image' only contains the last value since for loop assign new value to 'image' each time it loops.

【Question】

Since I want to store the images in one field(row) in mysql table, I need 'image' variable to contain all the 5 jpg images output.

something like:
image = 
xxx.example.com/examplefolder/image/1.jpg, xxx.example.com/examplefolder/image/2.jpg, xxx.example.com/examplefolder/image/3.jpg, xxx.example.com/examplefolder/image/4.jpg, xxx.example.com/examplefolder/image/5.jpg

so I can parse 'image' variable to mysql query.

I have no idea how to achieve this.

If you know or can give me some hint, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to store them in an array?

Comment: How does your sql query look like ?

Comment: Hi Thrustmaster,
Yes I believe if I can turn it into an array then it will achieve what I would like to achieve.

Hi Steinar Lima,
sql query look something like this:
cursor = db.cursor()

sql= ("""UPDATE %s SET image = %%s WHERE url = %%s""" % table_name,(image, url))
try:
    cursor.execute(*sql)
    db.commit()
finally:
    print("record written")

Comment: have you tried a list e.g., `images = []` before the loop and `images.append(image)` inside the loop? Read [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

> How to parse all the 'for loop' outputs to mysql update query as one variable

You can use a `list`. The list object will be *one variable*.

```
imgList = []
for image in soup.select('img[src^="/examplefolder/image/"]'):
    ..
    ..
    image = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, path)
    imgList.append(image)

# Use the list: imgList
print imgList  #Display the array of all the images you extracted.    

#Construct your SQL query to insert the images.
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I've tried using 'list' but for some reason the script dies after the first loop and it doesn't write to the mysql.

However, I can see it is returning me the valuables in string as you suggested.

Comment: I think it is unicode compatibility issues with beautifulsoup/mysql.

at the moment I receive output in such manner:
[u'xxx.1jpb', u'xxx.2.jpg' .. and so on] I believe I need to get rid of unicode.

Do you happened to know how to output result of 'list' in none unicode style. in other word to get rid of u'' ??

Comment: I finally got it solved.
as you suggested I used list, I encoded the image in utf-8 then wrapped it in str(). 
Thanks for you help!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the mysql query you want to execute, but you could just do the mysql call in the same for-loop. That would do one mysql query per image.

```
for image in soup.select('img[src^="/examplefolder/image/"]'):
    # ...
    image = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, path)
    # mysql query using image
```

If you want to do something more complicated, just store the images in a list:

```
images = []
for image in soup.select('img[src^="/examplefolder/image/"]'):
    # ...
    images.append(urlparse.urljoin(base_url, path))
```

And then you can iterate over the images or create a complex mysql query.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment.
I have whole other chunk of query before and after this particular section so I would really like to store it in one variable.
Thanks for your advise!